# Client Side Resource refreshing

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

Whenever we make changes to JS files, browsers cache the previous version of the client resources. Due to this, the changes are not reflected across the build.

Can any one suggest what is the best way to get this solved?

I wish the new resource to be requested by the browser only after a new build and for every other time the cached resource could just be fine as it helps performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supply a version parameter in the URL. Basically,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=${app.version}" />
<script src="js/script.js?v=${app.version}"></script>
```

wherein the `${app.version}` is an application wide variable which returns an integer or decimal value or maybe just the timestamp of the server's startup time. If the request parameter value changes, then the client is forced to send a new request on it.

Comment: But if the page is idle and you do the deployment or have neew version of JS file than how will browser know to get the new version without any action?

Comment: @Viral: Not. User has just to refresh the page. Any action which require a logged-in user would also fail anyway as the session has expired.